# asynchronus data calls for j2me

Tags: java-me, asynchronous

I have to do this project which ask me to implement an asynchronus data calling for j2me, whole idea behing the implementation is to cache the data via asynchoronus calls that reduces the latency when the data stream is too big. i have a little experience in implementing j2me applilcations and ajax+php web pages. but i can't understand how to tackle this problem, where to start implementation.